# Can I negotiate for fellowships from a graduate department before accepting their offer?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding, united-states

I have currently been accepted to Ph.D. in CS programs at 2 schools in the USA (let's call them A and B). Both have offered 5 years of TA/RA funding. A is my preferred choice, but I haven't accepted the offer formally since I'm waiting to hear from a couple of other places.

However, school B is offering a fellowship in my first year in addition to TA/RA, which would be helpful as I am planning to attend a conference in Europe in September (not sure if new students get travel grants that early).

Is it acceptable to contact school A and ask if I could be considered for any incoming student fellowships (I know they have at least one) BEFORE actually accepting their offer? If so, should I mention that I have fellowship offers from other schools and/or my interest in attending the conference?

Note: I have an oral paper under review at this conference as the first author, and my advisor is confident it will be accepted, but I'll only know for sure in late April. Also, even if the paper is rejected and I do not have to attend, a fellowship will be useful in attending any other conference, not to mention boosting my academic profile.